# Python: group by time and space

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, haversine

```
    ID  timestamp                lat          lon
0   A   2020-03-20 00:17:10 42.360000   -71.090000
1   A   2020-03-20 00:20:51 42.360000   -71.090000
2   A   2020-03-20 00:35:31 42.360000   -71.090000
3   A   2020-03-20 00:35:34 42.360000   -71.090000
4   B   2020-03-20 01:48:14 42.360000   -71.100000
5   B   2020-03-20 03:15:00 42.360000   -71.100000
6   C   2020-03-20 11:05:47 42.365259   -71.103502
7   D   2020-03-20 10:53:43 42.363174   -71.096756
8   D   2020-03-20 10:57:45 42.363260   -71.095598
9   D   2020-03-20 11:04:24 42.363303   -71.094997
```

I would like to see if there is an overlap between two users in a radius of `100` meters anytime during the days for at least `10` seconds. I would like to have an output like the following

```
df
      usuerI     userJ     centroid.lat  centroid.lon     time
0      A          B         42.360000      -71.094997      33s
1      B          D         42.365259      -71.103502      5s
```

Answer (score 0):

I added some extra rows to make your data work better for this example. It's worth noting that this method would need considerable optimization and error handling to scale well.

```
   ID  timestamp                lat          lon
0   A   2020-03-20 00:17:10 42.360000   -71.090000
1   A   2020-03-20 00:20:51 42.360000   -71.090000
2   A   2020-03-20 00:35:31 42.360000   -71.090000
3   A   2020-03-20 00:35:34 42.360000   -71.090000
4   B   2020-03-20 01:48:14 42.360000   -71.100000
5   B   2020-03-20 03:15:00 42.360000   -71.100000
6   C   2020-03-20 11:05:47 42.365259   -71.103502
7   D   2020-03-20 10:53:43 42.363174   -71.096756
8   D   2020-03-20 10:57:45 42.363260   -71.095598
9   D   2020-03-20 11:04:24 42.363303   -71.094997
10  E   2020-03-20 00:35:33 42.360001   -71.090001
11  F   2020-03-20 01:48:15 42.360003   -71.100099
```

Next we need to condition the df a bit.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r"[ ]{2,}")
df['lat_fix'] = df['lat'].str[-10:]
df['time'] = df['lat'].str[0:19] 
df['ID'] = df['timestamp']
df['lat'] = df['lat_fix']
df = df[['ID', 'time', 'lat', 'lon']]
df['lat'] = pd.to_numeric(df['lat'])
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['idx'] = range(0, df.shape[0])
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
```

Then we find the points within the distance threshold. The distance_thresh_list stores a list of lists, where the sublists contain the idx values for each group of points less than ~100m from each other.

```
x, y = df['lon'], df['lat'] 
points = np.array(list(zip(x.ravel(), y.ravel())))
tree = spatial.cKDTree(points)

distance_thresh_list = []
for p in points:
#0.0009 in decimal degrees is very close to 100m
    x = tree.query_ball_point(p, 0.0009)
    if len(x) > 1 and x not in distance_thresh_list:
        distance_thresh_list.append(x)
```

Then we look for unique IDs.

```
spatial_matches_list = []
df_spatial_match_list = []

for i in distance_thresh_list:
    df_slice = df[df['idx'].isin(i)]
    uniq_id_list = df_slice.ID.unique().tolist()
    if len(uniq_id_list) > 1 and uniq_id_list not in spatial_matches_list:
        print(uniq_id_list)
        spatial_matches_list.append(uniq_id_list)

        df_spatial_match = df[df['ID'].isin(uniq_id_list)]

        df_spatial_match = df[df['idx'].isin(i)]
        print(i)
        print(df_spatial_match)

        df_spatial_match_list.append(df_spatial_match)
```

Finally, we look for time matches.

```
for df in df_spatial_match_list:
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        before_window = idx + datetime.timedelta(seconds=-10)

        after_window = idx + datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)

        df_spatial_match_slice = df[(df.index.get_level_values(0) >= before_window) & (df.index.get_level_values(0) <= after_window)]

        if len(df_spatial_match_slice['ID'].unique().tolist()) > 1:
            print(df_spatial_match_slice)
```

Here are the matches (with duplicates).

```
                    ID        lat        lon  idx
time                                             
2020-03-20 00:35:31  A  42.360000 -71.090000    2
2020-03-20 00:35:34  A  42.360000 -71.090000    3
2020-03-20 00:35:33  E  42.360001 -71.090001   10
                    ID        lat        lon  idx
time                                             
2020-03-20 00:35:31  A  42.360000 -71.090000    2
2020-03-20 00:35:34  A  42.360000 -71.090000    3
2020-03-20 00:35:33  E  42.360001 -71.090001   10
                    ID        lat        lon  idx
time                                             
2020-03-20 00:35:31  A  42.360000 -71.090000    2
2020-03-20 00:35:34  A  42.360000 -71.090000    3
2020-03-20 00:35:33  E  42.360001 -71.090001   10
                    ID        lat        lon  idx
time                                             
2020-03-20 01:48:14  B  42.360000 -71.100000    4
2020-03-20 01:48:15  F  42.360003 -71.100099   11
                    ID        lat        lon  idx
time                                             
2020-03-20 01:48:14  B  42.360000 -71.100000    4
2020-03-20 01:48:15  F  42.360003 -71.100099   11
```

So the code above only looks to see if IDs are near each other within a window of time. If we want to calculate how much time IDs are near each other we can do this.

```
id_min_max_dict = {}

for i in df_spatial_match_slice_list:
    for j in i.ID.unique().tolist():

        id_slice = i.loc[i['ID'] == j]
        id_slice_time_max = id_slice.index.max()
        id_slice_time_min = id_slice.index.min()

        id_min_max_dict[j] = [id_slice_time_min, id_slice_time_max]
```

Once we have a dict to store the time ranges, we can see how many shared seconds there are between IDs at the same location.

```
for i in spatial_matches_list:
    print(i)
    time_range1 = pd.date_range(id_min_max_dict[i[0]][0], id_min_max_dict[i[0]][1], freq='S') 
    time_range2 = pd.date_range(id_min_max_dict[i[1]][0], id_min_max_dict[i[1]][1], freq='S')


    time_range_intersection = time_range1.intersection(time_range2)
    print(time_range_intersection)
    print(str(len(time_range_intersection)) + ' seconds of time within ~100m')
```

So the time/location intersections look like this. FWIW, this isn't very exciting without more sample data rows, and this method will need additional complexity to work with more than 2 unique IDs.

```
['A', 'E']
DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-20 00:35:33'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
1 seconds of time within ~100m
['B', 'F']
DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
0 seconds of time within ~100m
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you tried but you could for example start like this.
I did not take the 10 second timing in account but it is easy to add. I used for the distance measure the `geopy.distance.distance`. The code below stores the encounters in a list from which you can easily build a new dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import geopy.distance

# threshold distance in km
threshold_distance = 0.1

# list of IDs
id_list = list(df.index.levels[1])

# combinations of IDs
combs = list(combinations(id_list, 2))

# list to store the indices of the meetings
meetings = []

# go through combinations
for i, j in combs:

    # get the indices (numbers) of both IDs
    i_indices = [a[0] for a in df.iloc[df.index.get_level_values(1) == i].index.values]
    j_indices = [a[0] for a in df.iloc[df.index.get_level_values(1) == j].index.values]


    # go through the ID's data
    for i_index in i_indices:
        for j_index in j_indices:
                # if the date coincides
                if df.at[(i_index, i), "date"]!=df.at[(j_index, j), "date"]:
                    continue

                # use geopy to calculate the distance from the coordinates
                coords1 = (df.at[(i_index,i),"lat"],df.at[(i_index, i),"lon"])
                coords2 = (df.at[(j_index,j),"lat"],df.at[(j_index, j),"lon"])
                if geopy.distance.distance(coords1, coords2).km < threshold_distance:
                    meetings.append((i_index, j_index))
```